# How to create a new page in Sitecore

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, sitecore, ascx

I need to add a page in Sitecore:

- `abc.com/link1?id=1*something=BLABLA`
- `abc.com/link2?id=2*something=BLABLA`
- `abc.com/linkN?id=N*something=BLABLA`

All of the links above represent a single page, which in turn serves the user a template based on `link1`, `link2`... `linkN`.

Comment: See if this helps: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/02/sitecore-product-urls-amazon-style.html
I think you can also use HttpHandlers if things don't work out. It's been a while since I used Sitecore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you can just create three new items (**link1**, **link2**, and **linkN**). These items can share the same "base" template that contains everything they have in common (Layout, common/shared Controls, etc.). Form there, if you need each one to be slightly different, you can create a new set of templates for each item that inherit from the base template (recommended), or modify the presentation details on each item directly.

That said, if you truly need a ***single item*** that accepts multiple routes and query strings, you have a few options:

1. If the item exists at the root of your site, you can create a single
   item and make [Aliases](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Aliases.aspx) for any other names you wish to route to
   the item. For example, an item named **link** can have aliases for
   **link1**, **link2**, **linkN**, etc. The query strings will work across all aliased pages. Using this approach, you would not be changing "Layout" as you described. Rather, your Layout (or one or more Sublayouts) would react to the available query strings and offer up different views and/or behavior. I like to call this making the Sublayout "smarter" :)
2. If you need a more robust solution that allows routing beyond the
   root of the site, you may want to look into extending the
   UrlResolver in the HttpRequest pipeline.

Comment: i am actully totally new to the site core. can you please tell me how to create item i can find layout and template in th gui of site core but cant find item please explain in detail `create three new items (link1, link2, and linkN). These items can share the same "base" template that contains everything they have in common (Layout, common/shared Controls, etc.). Form there, if you need each one to be slightly different, you can create a new set of templates for each item that inherit from the base template (recommended)`

Comment: Ok, no problem, it sounds like you are very new to Sitecore. I would read through [this tutorial](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/training%20materials/basic%20site/selfstudyguide-buildingaverysimplewebsite_usletter.pdf) before digging in too deep. You may also want to attend Sitecore Developer training in Mill Valley. There are lots of moving parts to even the simplest of pages in Sitecore and it's best to take it slow and really understand what each piece does.

Answer (score 1):

This is also a link that may prove helpful [Learn sitecore](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2011/03/Info-site-8-unified-page-editor.aspx).  Very succinctly, my general approach is to create a template, create a page under content, then assign a layout that links it up to asp.net stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a single item to handle all the three links, you can also use a wildcard item in which you read the querystring from the httpcontext and do whatever you want to do based on the querystring.

Another thing that comes to my mind when looking at your question is: What do you want to achieve with the querystings? At might be me but this looks a bit like you are trying to create a Sitecore site with the techniques of joomla (or other cms) based urls.